# Heredocs, variables and single quotes in BASH and MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, variables, heredoc

I'm trying to send some data to a remote MySQL database using a BASH script on GNU/Linux, but get various errors.. Here's the line that's not working:

```
mysql --host=192.168.0.100 --user=petercapaldi --password=mypassword mystartrekcharacterbase << EOF
INSERT into myfourlegs values ('$PERSON','$THETIME','$THETIME','$THEDATE','$DAYOFWEEK');
EOF
```

and this too (just in case):

```
mysql --host=192.168.0.100 --user=petercapaldi --password=mypassword mystartrekcharacterbase << EOF
INSERT into myfourlegs values (\047$PERSON\047,\047$THETIME\047,\047$THETIME\047,\047$THEDATE\047,\047$DAYOFWEEK\047);
EOF
```

Comment: Can you try backquotes instead? e.g. `\\`$PERSON\\``

Comment: @shellter It's just a local IP address. I don't think that would really matter for him.

Comment: It's a fake local IP, I just smudged the characters round a bit :) Solved the issue now, it was me being an idiot and missing the ID from the database.. The single quotes print out as they should (i.e. the variables print out with the quotes around them)

Answer (score 1):

Scrap that. My fault - missed the first field in the database. The single quotes work as they should with heredocs.. (i.e. '$VARIABLE' prints 'myvariable' just like $VARIABLE prints myvariable).

Comment: Have you thought about what to do if a variable contains a single quote?

Comment: I haven't no :/ None of them should, as it's basically a staff clocking-in machine (running on a Raspberry Pi - gone a bit mad with them here). But it's a possibility that a staff member's name may contain one.. What would be your suggestion there?